# ConTeXt module like overpic in Latex

Tags: overlays, overpic, layers

Is there an analogue of the overpic package in ConTeXt for placing letter labels on images? Not one image, as in the Wiki examples and in "It's in the details" manual, but several, as with subfigures (a,b,....g)